# ionic using get previous page name

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I need get previous page name.

here is my code.

```
 @ViewChild(Nav) nav:Nav
  constructor() {
    this.nav_app.viewDidEnter.subscribe(
      view => console.log("Current opened view is : " + view.name);
    )
  }
```

still i am getting

```
Current opened view is : t
```

How can i get previous page name.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: Is this the app.component.ts? which page would you have before that?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Ya app.component.ts.app opened first page  is login page.

Answer (score 12):

You can try

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
export class MyApp {

    constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){
        var val=this.navCtrl.last();
        console.log("VAL");
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It's wrk fine .. : )

Comment: please upvote and approve my answer, if it helps. :)

Comment: to upvote: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: to approve as right answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: you can click on UP arrow on the left side of the answer to upvote and a TICK mark below the down arrow to approve as correct answer

Comment: I have one doubt.How can i get use this app component.ts

Comment: do you want previous page on  every navigation?

Comment: For ionic4 solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62851249/1188605

Answer (score 2):

In ionic +2 you can simply use:

```
this.navCtrl.last().name
```

Here is a simple example to log the name

```
constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){
    console.log("Previous Page is called = " + this.navCtrl.last().name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a **history/previous** page name in ionic you can use this.

> `this.navCtrl.getPrevious().name;`

or

> `this.nav.getPrevious().name;`