# get last view Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework

good morning. Does anyone know the import of the NavController? I am looking at the docs of Ionic 4 [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav) and it says there is a method of getPrevious() however when I do:

```js
import { NavController } from ‘@Ionic/angular’;

contructor (private navCtrl: NavController){}

private func(): void{
  this.navCtrl.getPrevious();
}
```

I get an error saying `property getPrevious does not exist on type NavController` however in the docs it says that it exists. anyone aware of the proper import since it isn't documented?

[previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544646/ionic-using-get-previous-page-name) you were able to do this with Ionic 2-3 but not Ionic 4.

*side note** method `last()` doesn't exist either.

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue in ionic4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62851249/1188605

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? If you want to go back, than you could use the ion-back-button.

```
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button color="light"></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
```

Also you can use the NavController like this to get forward:

```
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) { }

  GotoImpressum() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('impressum');
  }
```